Can’t open one half of a patio door (need to square the door frame)
Edit: per a comment, I measured the frame and it’s not square so the question now is “How do I square this?”
I have these double French door that open inwards, but the pane on the right in the picture is so pressed up against the top that I can’t open it. I can open the left side, but as you can see there’s a massive gap at the top and it rubs at the bottom.
A few important points:

we bought the house 4 years ago and had the foundation inspected and were told that it was fine (I’m wondering if the house itself is shifting)
we had handymen come out to fix it and they got it working by doing work on the hinges (they set bigger screws into the frame), but it quickly reverted.
The house is very old and other doors do shift as well, but not nearly as much

I would love to understand the foot cause, but I don’t know how to go about figuring it out. If it is just the house shifting, does that mean this would probably still happen even if I replace the door?



See if the door frame is square.  Measure from top right corner to bottom left.  Repeat with top left corner to bottom right.  Both measures should be the same.  Use two people to get exact measurements.  Come back and edit your question with the measurements or ask a second about squaring a door frame.

It’s 99.5 x 101…

Is that both measurements?  The door frame, not the doors.  If so then the doors hinges are not right.

Yeah that’s from top right corner of the frame to bottom left of the frame and same on the other side… what does this mean? Do I have someone come and adjust the hinges or do I need to replace the whole frame?

@crip659 99.5 and 101 isn't square though, is it?  The "top right to bottom left" being shorter tells me the top of the frame is shifted to the left (which doesn't really jive with what we see, but maybe it depends whether right and left are looking in or out).

@Huesmann   Have no idea what I was thinking of.  The x must have thrown me off.  You are absolutely correct.  Hope the builders used thick shims when putting the frame in.

Okay I added a picture with the measurement just to make it clear.
I’m trying to figure out if this is something I can fix myself or if I need someone to come.
What’s perplexing me though is that it was fine at some point, but maybe that’s just the house shifting.
